# Python mix-in enumerations as dictionary key: how the type is converted?

Tags: python, dictionary, enums, mixins

Here is the code:

```
from enum import Enum

class EFoo(str, Enum):
    A = 'e1'
    B = 'e2'

print(EFoo.A)

d = {
    EFoo.A : 'eA',
    EFoo.B : 'eB'
}

first_key = list(d.keys())[0]
first_key_type = type(first_key)

print("Keys: " + str(d.keys()))
print("Type of first key: " + str(first_key_type))
print("d[EFoo.A] = '" + d[EFoo.A] + "'")
print("d['e1'] = '" + d['e1'] + "'")
```

Here is the output (Python 3.5)

```
EFoo.A  
Keys: dict_keys([<EFoo.A: 'e1'>, <EFoo.B: 'e2'>])  
Type of first key: <enum 'EFoo'>  
d[EFoo.A] = 'eA'  
d['e1'] = 'eA'
```

Now the type of the dictionary keys is `<enum 'EFoo'>`.

So I don't understand why the code `d['e1'] = 'eA'`, which access the dictionary by a **string** key, works.

Is the string "e1" converted to an "EFoo" instance? Does Python do some reverse lookup to find the correct enum value to convert to?

Moreover, if you remove the `str` as a parent of the class, so that the class declaration looks like `class EFoo(Enum):`, the above code snippet does not work anymore
What does inheriting from `str` exactly do in this case?

Comment: This is so cool. I didn't know it was possible to have enum-valued keys in a python dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

`EFoo` inherits from `str`, so it is a `str` -- that is how inheritance works.  Because `EFoo` inherits from `str` all its members are `str`s as well as `Efoo`s, so standard `str` operations work:

```
>>> isinstance(EFoo.A, str)
True
>>> EFoo.A.upper()
E1
>>> EFoo.A + EFoo.B
e1e2
```

Inheriting from `str` (or any other base type) does remove some of the safeties built in to `Enum`, so you should only do it if necessary (such as replacing existing constants of that type already in your code).

Comment: It seems like `str` enums are a nice step up for global `str` constants.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the enums inherit the `str` magic methods, so:

```
print("EFoo.A == 'e1'", EFoo.A == 'e1')
print("EFoo.A == 'e2'", EFoo.A == 'e2')
```

output:

```
EFoo.A == 'e1' True
EFoo.A == 'e2' False
```

I imagine this will allow `dict` to take a string parameter and match it to one of the keys.